# Custom template or theme (header and footer) for PDP page in Magento

Tags: php, templates, magento, themes

We're redoing our theme in Magento to use a grid system (semantic.gs), and I've been tasked with the duty setting up the PDP page to use this new grid system template. We eventually will want this template on all pages, but for now, it's been specifically requested ONLY on the PDP page. So basically I want to set a custom theme/template (including header and footer, not just columns) that I can load on certain pages. Can anyone point me in the direction of how to go about doing this? Extensive SO and google searching has come up pretty fruitless.

So far:

I created a new layout called 2columns-left-grid.phtml in app/design/frontend/[my_interface]/[my_theme]/template/page

I modified these lines:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
```

To be:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header2') ?>
```

and

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer2') ?>
```

I duplicated header.phtml and named it header2.phtml, and duplicated footer.phtml and named it footer2.html

My questions:
Will this work, and if so, what other code do I need to modify (xml files, etc)
How can I get this template to apply ONLY to the PDP page for now?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello you can override product tag

< catalog_product_view translate="label">

> /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml

from into your new module layout xml

Comment: Magik, this is exactly what I'm looking for, thank you! I created a new template and modified the catalog.xml file to use it, and it's loading properly. One more thing: If I want to load a separate header and footer, how would I go about doing that? Can I do something like `<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header2') ?>` and then create a header2.phtml? Is there code I need to add to make the `$this->getChildHtml('header2')` able to call the header2.phtml? Let me know if I should start a new question or if this has already been answered. Will accept this answer